# Adding several geoJSON layers in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I have two geoJSON files, one is for drawing the lines(states.js), and another one is for adding markers on the map (marker.js).

However, when I add a line of code that is supposed to be adding the marker layer, nothing works.

```
var markerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(markers).addTo(map);
```

How should I approach this? I thought featureLayer would work to add multiple layers, but it doesn't seem to be working well. Help is much appreciated.

Working example so far: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmZcskJSsDMUZz3FfHco?p=preview)

Example I'm following is [here](http://www.example.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things wrong here. You forgot to declare your global `L.mapbox.accessToken`:

```
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia2thZ2lsbCIsImEiOiJjaWdsdmJjeWkwMjMwdWFrcjI4eGZ3MGd2In0.WslWCpxaXxUOgUZP_VT1cg';
```

You're adding the statesData twice, once in a `L.mapbox.featureLayer` and once in a `L.GeoJSON`:

```
var statesLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(statesData).addTo(map);

statesLayer = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Once is more than enough: here's a example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kV8h69VJt2jtpqwdCpJo?p=preview